# Can vector spaces occupy a large cardinal amount of dimensions?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, large-cardinals

So far I have found that a vector space of [uncountably infinite dimensions](https://minhyongkim.wordpress.com/2013/10/23/a-vector-space-of-uncountable-dimension/) is mathematically valid, but what about vector spaces that can occupy, say, an inaccessible or Mahlo cardinal amount of dimensions? I haven't found anything online regarding vector spaces with dimensions above $\aleph_1$; so any help is appreciated here.

Comment: It's not a large cardinal, but you've definitely seen vector spaces with dimension $\mathfrak{c}$ (for instance $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space), and in the absence of CH this is larger than $\aleph_1$-dimensional.

Comment: Any non-empty set a basis for some vector space ( and the dimension of this vector space is the cardinality of the set you started with).